# Jenkins presend script modification

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Iam trying to modify the default presend script of a Jenkins project, As I need to send different email message for the Success and Failure.

Right now My Default content has a success message content which is an output of batch file and works like a champ but when the job is failed, Iam getting the same message which doesn't make sense..

Pls advice how to fix the presend script to send the correct message based on the condition.

Comment: Could you plz share your pre-send script ?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.. I did this using triggers